# Module not found: Can't resolve 'xlsx' in 'filelocation\node_modules\cptable-fixed-xlsx-style'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, node-modules

We have tried ServerSideRendering for our web application, so we acheived it using ( https://github.com/axeldelafosse/expo-next-monorepo-example ) custom mono-repo-application which will support both node and next js.
While running my build command I am facing this can't resolve xlsx error in cptable-fixed-xlsx-style package.

I'm using nextjs latest version 12 and webpack 5 & cptable-fixed-xlsx-style 0.8.20

Erorr message in terminal:

```
../../node_modules/cptable-fixed-xlsx-style/ods.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'xlsx' in 'filelocation\node_modules\cptable-fixed-xlsx-style'
Did you mean './xlsx'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

Import trace for requested module:
../../node_modules/cptable-fixed-xlsx-style/xlsx.js
../app/src/components/Applications/Tabs/CreditTransactions.tsx
../app/LoanManagementApp.tsx
../app/App.tsx
./src/pages/index.tsx
```

Our next.config.js:

```
// @ts-check

/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 **/
 
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = Infinity; 

const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter')
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
const withFonts = require('next-fonts')
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true'
})
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  'app',
  '@gorhom/bottom-sheet',
  '@gorhom/portal',
  'dripsy',
  '@dripsy/core',
  'recyclerlistview'
])

const nextConfig = {
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
  compress: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };

    return config;
  },
}

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    withTM,
    withFonts,
    withBundleAnalyzer,
    [withExpo, { projectRoot: __dirname + '/../..' }]
  ],
  nextConfig
)
```

ods.js

```
/* ods.js (C) 2014 SheetJS -- http://sheetjs.com */
/* vim: set ts=2: */
/*jshint -W041 */
var ODS = {};
(function make_ods(ODS) {
/* Open Document Format for Office Applications (OpenDocument) Version 1.2 */
var get_utils = function() {
    if(typeof XLSX !== 'undefined') return XLSX.utils;
    if(typeof module !== "undefined" && typeof require !== 'undefined') try {
        return require('../' + 'xlsx').utils;
    } catch(e) {
        try { return require('./' + 'xlsx').utils; }
        catch(ee) { return require('xl' + 'sx').utils; }
    }
    throw new Error("Cannot find XLSX utils");
};
```

So I have tried some configurations to overcome this error but not able rectify this error. Is there any fix for this error?